# canvas with Image rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

now I want to rotate a picture. if the pic not be change . My code  is  right. But if I change my Pic my pic in canvas will be disappear . The first code is the pic not be change .The last is the pic to be change.

```js
function rotateImg(direction) {
  var min_step = 0;
  var max_step = 3;
         var step = $(currentSource).attr("step");
        var id = $(".active")[0].id;
  if (step == null) {
   step = min_step;
  }
  if (direction == 'right') {
   step++;
            step > max_step && (step = min_step);
  } else {
   step--;
   step < min_step && (step = max_step);
  }
  $(currentSource).attr("step", step);
  var canvas = $("#canvas"+id)[0];
  var width = canvas.width;
  var height = canvas.height;
  var src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  var img = new Image();
  var degree = step * 90 * Math.PI / 180;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  switch (step) {
   case 0:
    canvas.width = height;
    canvas.height = width;
    ctx.drawImage(currentSource, 0, 0,height,width);
    break;
   case 1:
    canvas.width = height;
    canvas.height = width;
    ctx.rotate(degree);
    ctx.drawImage(currentSource, 0, -height,width,height);
    break;
   case 2:
    canvas.width = height;
    canvas.height = width;
    ctx.rotate(degree);
    ctx.drawImage(currentSource, -height,-width ,height,width);
    break;
   case 3:
    canvas.width = height;
    canvas.height = width;
    ctx.rotate(degree);
    ctx.drawImage(currentSource, -width, 0,width,height);
    break;
  }
 }
```

```js
function rotateImg(direction) {
  var min_step = 0;
  var max_step = 3;
         var step = $(currentSource).attr("step");
        var id = $(".active")[0].id;
  if (step == null) {
   step = min_step;
  }
  if (direction == 'right') {
   step++;
            step > max_step && (step = min_step);
  } else {
   step--;
   step < min_step && (step = max_step);
  }
  $(currentSource).attr("step", step);
  var canvas = $("#canvas"+id)[0];
  var width = canvas.width;
  var height = canvas.height;
  var src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  var imgs;
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = src;
  img.setAttribute("step",step);
  imgs = img;
  var degree = step * 90 * Math.PI / 180;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  switch (step) {
   case 0:
    canvas.width = height;
    canvas.height = width;
    ctx.drawImage(imgs, 0, 0,height,width);
    break;
   case 1:
    canvas.width = height;
    canvas.height = width;
    ctx.rotate(degree);
    ctx.drawImage(imgs, 0, -height,width,height);
    break;
   case 2:
    canvas.width = height;
    canvas.height = width;
    ctx.rotate(degree);
    ctx.drawImage(imgs, -height,-width ,height,width);
    break;
   case 3:
    canvas.width = height;
    canvas.height = width;
    ctx.rotate(degree);
    ctx.drawImage(imgs, -width, 0,width,height);
    break;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Please provide a working snippet